# Автоматическое изменение статуса заказа по полученной от другого сервера информации

Tags: python, mysql, django

В общем, такое дело. Есть у меня модель заказа и у этой модели, в свою очередь, есть поле paid и поле status. Поле paid - BoleanField. Оно должно менять в зависимости от того, оплатил человек заказ или нет.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    
    CHOICESSTATUS = {
        ('Оформлен', 'Оформлен'),
        ('Оплачен', 'Оплачен'),
        ('Отправлен', 'Отправлен'),
    }
    .........
    .........
    first_name = models.CharField('Имя', max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField('Фамилия', max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    created = models.DateTimeField('Создано', auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField('Обновлено', auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField('Оплачено', default=False)
    status = models.CharField('Статус', max_length=100, default="Оформлен", choices=CHOICESSTATUS)
    currency = models.CharField('Валюта', max_length=100, default="BYN", choices=CHOICES)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='orders', verbose_name="Заказы")
    .........
    .........
```

Я настроил, чтобы сервер платежной системы(Ассист) присылал на страницу детали конкретного заказа. И там есть статус заказа. Мне нужно каким-то образом брать с этой страницы данные о заказе и, в зависимости от того, что там написано, менять значение поля paid с `False` на `True`

В шаблоне есть форма, нажав на которую перекидывает на страницу, не связанную с моим сайтом.

```
<FORM ACTION="УРЛ НЕ СВЯЗАННЫЙ С САЙТОМ" METHOD="POST"> 
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Ordernumber" VALUE="{{ order.id }}"> 
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Merchant_ID" VALUE="******">
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Login" VALUE="*****">
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Password" VALUE="******">
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Startyear" VALUE="{{ order.created|date:"Y" }}"> 
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Startmonth" VALUE="{{ order.created|date:"m" }}"> 
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Startday" VALUE="{{ order.created|date:"d" }}"> 
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Starthour" VALUE="00"> 
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Startmin" VALUE="00"> 
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Endyear" VALUE="{{ order.created|date:"Y" }}"> 
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Endmonth" VALUE="{{ order.created|date:"m" }}"> 
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Endday" VALUE="{{ order.created|date:"d"|add:3 }}"> 
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Endhour" VALUE="23">
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Endmin" VALUE="59"> 
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Format" VALUE="3"> 
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Language" VALUE="RU"> 
  <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="Submit" VALUE="Выполнить"> 
</FORM>
```

После нажатия кнопки "Выполнить", перекидывает на страницу и инфа о заказе на этой странице представлена в формате xml. Выглядит это так:

[image: Данные о заказе в формате xml]

Comment: Нужно, чтобы Ваша платёжка присылала на какой-то роут инфу о заказе (например статус и его ID). Как только на этот роут приходит запрос, ваш веб-сервер проверяет откуда вообще пришел запрос (чтобы умники мамкины не оплачивали через curl), далее пишет в БД для этого заказа нужный статус. Вот и всё

Comment: Поддержу предыдущего комментатора - логичнее это оформить в качестве метода REST-API, нежели брать данные с формы на клиенте. Все, что происходит на клиенте - не надежно и нельзя этому доверять. Поэтому - только межсервисная интеграция